# Can I Use SharePoint's Web Services to Edit a Content Editor Web Part?

Tags: web-services, content-editor-web-part

Is it possible for me to change both the properties & the HTML of a content editor web part on a publishing page using SharePoint 2010's web services? If so, would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

The contents of a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) are stored like any other web part - in the web part properties.

You can see this if you Export the web parts .dwp file and open in a text editor, you will get something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Content Editor</Title>
  ....
 <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">
  <![CDATA[​Testing...testing...1..2..3]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
```

The contents are in the `Content` element. (testing...testing...)

You can read and write the web part properties using the [WebPartPagesWebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcwebpartpages.webpartpageswebservice_members.aspx) - see GetWebPart and SaveWebPart

Answer (score 1):

Actually YES (thanks Ryan)!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcwebpartpages.webpartpageswebservice.savewebpart.aspx

Comment: Actually you can - see WebPartPagesWebService.SaveWebPart